# Take a Chance on Me

Tags: riddle, word

I began as an expert

But later my skills are still recognized.

Once a fire was started within me

And after asking why I did it all

You'll find I was heavy into gambling.

Hint 1:

> What is another name for an expert?

Hint 1b:

> Payment is important for this expert.

Hint 2:

> What is another term for skills?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Riddle haters still lurking around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's

> PROBABILITY

Firstly, this fits the title.

*I began as an expert*

> A **pro**

*But later my skills are still recognized.*

> My **ability**

*Once a fire was started within me*

> I started to burn ... we want the first letter of the word **b**urn. (Alternatively this could mean **lit**, which appears in the word probability - thanks Moghwyn!)

*And after asking why I did it all*

> "why" = Y, at the end of the word

*You'll find I was heavy into gambling.*

> Well, that could be just another reference to the whole thing, like the title.

Comment: Very nice! Perfectly done.

Answer (score 4):

I began as an expert

> Also known as a "pro".

But later my skills are still recognized.

> Due to your "abilities".

Once a fire was started within me

> The fire was "lit".

And after asking why I did it all
You'll find I was heavy into gambling.

> Putting it all together, gambling is based on "probabilities", which I assume to be the answer.

Comment: Two minutes too late, I should type faster. :-)

Comment: Ninja'd, I'm afraid! :-) +1 anyway.

Comment: Nicely done as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> Better?

Expert, recognized skills:

> Better ability than peers.

Fire 'within':

> Inner letters are "ette", which is apparently colloquial for an incensed feeling http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ette.

Gambling:

> someone who bets = better.

It doesn't fits the hint particularly well, though.

Comment: Very nice try. Not quite what I am looking for. You've actually hit on something in your second section that is worth looking at more.